# Use of Jquery on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, onscroll, onscrolllistener

I am unable to show text in console.log when I scroll the page.

```js
$("#idOfUl").on('scroll', function() {
  console.log('Event Fired');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="idOfUl">
  <ul>
    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>

    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>

    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>

    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>

    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>


    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

I am unable to show text in console.log when I scroll the page.

I am unable to show text in console.log when I scroll the page.

I am unable to show text in console.log when I scroll the page.

I am unable to show text in console.log when I scroll the page.

I am unable to show text in console.log when I scroll the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element needs to be scrollable (fixed height with an `overflow:scroll`).

```js
$("#idOfUl").scroll(function() {
  console.log('Event Fired');
});
```

```css
#idOfUl {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="idOfUl">
  <ul>
    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>

    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>

    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>

    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>

    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>


    <li>
      You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow
      property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible. You can use the overflow property when
      you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.
    </li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: I tried jsfiddle.net/u7fv9tnL/2 , but nothing happens.

Comment: `height:100%` won't do the trick, try `height:100vh` - I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks it helped me out, I have a question for smooth reload iframe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67765152/iframe-smooth-reload-refresh will be thankful, if you can advise there too.