# Iframe smooth reload / refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, bootstrap-4, onload-event

I have an iframe in my html page, which should be refreshed smoothly (no blinking). SO for that I tried to have two iframes together, but still it gets blinked sometimes when it is scrolled some down.

**task.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pending Tasks</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .sc_table {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <center>
    <h2>Pending Tasks</h2>
  </center>
  </div>

<div class="container-fluid p-2 sc_table b-5">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Testing of automation with SQL">Testing</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="retfgretgf">gdfrtdfrsg</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">5</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">6</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">7</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">8</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">9</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">10</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">11</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">12</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">13</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">14</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">15</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">16</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">17</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">18</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">19</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">20</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">21</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">22</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">23</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">24</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">25</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">26</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">27</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">28</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">29</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">30</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">31</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">32</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">33</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">34</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">35</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">36</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">37</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">38</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">39</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">40</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">41</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">42</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">43</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">44</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">45</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <th scope="row">46</th>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="title">2</td>
        <td><a href="?id=" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a></td>
      </tr>
    
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
<script>
$(".sc_table").scroll(function() {
localStorage.setItem('scpos', $(".sc_table").scrollTop());
 });

 function isetFrame() {
 var scrollpos = localStorage.getItem('scpos');
 $(".sc_table").scrollTop(scrollpos);
 }

 isetFrame();
 setInterval(isetFrame, 1);
 </script>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TV</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body,
  html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
  }


    .self-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

      .embed-responsive-item {
        flex-grow: 1;
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="self-container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">TV</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Task
            </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="?task=active">Active</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="?task=pending">Pending</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="?task=completed">Completed</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="?task=new">New</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      Network
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1 container-fluid">
    <iframe id="iframeid" class="embed-responsive-item" src="task.html"></iframe>
    <iframe id="iframeidc" class="embed-responsive-item" src="task.html"></iframe>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
<script>

function setFrame() {
  $('#iframeidc',window.parent.document).attr('src',$('#iframeid',window.parent.document).attr('src'));
$("#iframeidc").on("load", function (e) {
  $("#iframeidc").show()
  $("#iframeid").hide()
});
  $('#iframeid',window.parent.document).attr('src',$('#iframeidc',window.parent.document).attr('src'));
  $("#iframeid").on("load", function (e) {
  $("#iframeid").show()
  $("#iframeidc").hide()
  });
}

setFrame();
setInterval(setFrame, 1000);

</script>

</html>
```

I have an iframe in my html page, which should be refreshed smoothly (no blinking). SO for that I tried to have two iframes together, but still it gets blinked sometimes when it is scrolled some down.